# RadGrid GridTemplateColumn dynamically added insert mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I've RadGrid where I want to add a column dynamically so I've done something like this in page load

```
       GridTemplateColumn gtc = new GridTemplateColumn();
        gtc.DataField = "chqNumber";
        gtc.HeaderText = "Cheque Number";
        gtc.UniqueName = "chqNumber";
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(gtc);
```

It work fine, now I want to add textbox in this column as the user click "+add new record" on grid here is my code of itemCreated event

```
                    GridEditableItem gdit = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
                    RadTextBox txtBox = new RadTextBox();
                    txtBox.ID = "someIDWhatEver";
                   gdit["chqNumber"].Controls.Add(txtBox);
```

but this textbox gets added to another new column what I mean is this textbox does not added to same chqNumber column you can view my attached image which will illustrate better

as you can see my dynamic column gets added at the last even after insert and cancel button and dynamic textbox doesn't gets in this column please avoid my english grammatical mistakes :P

[image]

Comment: start from these articles http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/rows/accessing-cells-and-rows and http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/distinguish-edit-or-insert-mode to get exactly how to access the columns and know you are in insert mode. Also, create your columns in Page_Init. You can also use your own custom templates. See here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/defining-structure/creating-a-radgrid-programmatically#creating-template-columns-programmatically